# SQL query performance/SELECT TOP X behavior

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

was wondering why this query performs slowly.  If anyone could walk me through how its processed that would be great.  The DB being queried has over 500 million rows.  Is this query really that poorly written that a TOP 10 takes so long to complete it may as well never finish?  How might I improve the query assuming I still want to query data by month+year?

```
 SELECT TOP 10 *
 FROM ADB.dbo.Stuff tt
 WHERE MONTH(tt.SomeDate) = 5
 AND
 YEAR(tt.SomeDate) = 2011
```

Does SELECT TOP 10 not just halt after 10 results have been acquired?  Or does it take so long because it hasn't found my conditions yet while going through the 500m+ rows?

Thanks and sorry for such a simple question.

Comment: a `SELECT TOP 10` is kind of useless without an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @bluefeet . . . I disagree.  An order by might require scanning the entire table.  But as the question says, this should stop after hitting the first ten results.  Is this wrong?

Comment: @Gordon how could it stop after hitting the first 10 results? Do you think it stops at every row and applies MONTH and YEAR? And which results are really "the first ten results"? TOP *works* without ORDER BY (well not in all cases) but it's pretty meaningless when written that way.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Actually I do think it affects the query.  One way is if the optimizer switches from "optimize-for-full-result-set" to "optimize-for-first-row".  The help page for 2012 suggests this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) and in direct contrast to SET ROWCOUNT.  The documentation specifies "the first N number of random rows" . . . this is ambiguous, but it could mean that it finds the first N rows and then stops.  I sincerely doubt that it actually means "random" . . . more like "unspecified order".

Comment: @Gordon Can you show me a plan that demonstrates that MONTH() and YEAR() could possibly only be evaluated on 10 rows (or any number you specify by top) for a 500 million row table? Keep in mind these functions are applied in the *where clause* not in the select list.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . there is a misunderstanding.  MONTH() and YEAR() have to be evaluated on every row that is read in.  I was referring to the full table scan, which can stop after the tenth row is returned in the result set.  That might be on the tenth input row or the ten millionth.  But, the full table scan gets short-circuited (at least I hope so).  Not doing the full table scan would count as "useful" in my book.

Comment: @Gordon again, can you show me a plan where you see this short circuiting take place, when a where clause by definition will force a scan? In any case if you are right, how does adding an order by hurt? I'm not suggesting remove the top because it's stupid, I'm suggesting add an order by so the top has meaning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15376/discussion-between-gordon-linoff-and-aaron-bertrand)

Comment: FWIW I weighed in at Gordon & Aaron's chat with some interesting info from Paul White. So visit Gordon's "moved to chat" link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to scan the entire table because `MONTH(column)` and `YEAR(column)` are not sargable, and you haven't told SQL Server what you mean by `TOP`. While it's true that SQL Server may be able to short circuit onc it's found your 10 rows, it may be so far into the scan when that happens that the difference to you is minimal. This is especially true if you find zero rows or < 10 rows that match your where clause.

A much better `WHERE` clause would be:

```
WHERE SomeDate >= '20110501' AND SomeDate < '20110601';
```

If you don't want to construct the strings, you can pass those in as parameters / variables and do this:

```
DECLARE @year INT;
DECLARE @month INT;

SET @year = 2011;
SET @month = 5;

...
WHERE SomeDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, @month-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, '19000101'))
  AND SomeDate <  DATEADD(MONTH, @month,   DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, '19000101'));
```

In either case, if there is an index on `SomeDate`, it can be used and a table scan can be avoided. You want to avoid a table scan on a table with 500 million rows, even if you're only looking for 10 rows, and even if short circuiting might happen.

Even without a table scan, however, this query is still going to be inefficient. Do you really need all of the columns? If an index on `SomeDate` is used the seek will still have to do a lookup into the clustered index or a covering index to retrieve the rest of the columns. If you don't need those columns, don't include them.

And as bluefeet pointed out, this `TOP 10` stuff makes no sense if you haven't told SQL Server *which* 10 you mean, and you do that using `ORDER BY`. If the `ORDER BY` uses a suitable index you may avoid the additional costly sort operator you might think you're avoiding by not using `ORDER BY` anyway.

Comment: I'm still digesting your post but I just wanted to thank you for taking the time to give me all this great info.  I didn't know sargable conditions were even a thing!  I'm still learning and so I thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: FWIW, I've found cases where the DateAdd in a very large query led to a bad execution plan, apparently from the complexity of searching for the best plan. The cure was to calculate a `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` in variables before the query.

Comment: @ErikE I'd be interested to see such a plan, since the expression should always collapse to a constant scan.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right, it *should*, and I was very flummoxed. But the *only* change to the query in the SP was to move the date calculation on a constant out of the query and precalculate it first. Perhaps it had something to do with parameter sniffing?

Comment: Yes I've seen that before but it's not because of where the expression is - if you assign the params to a local variable and use that in the expression in the query you should have seen the same change.